# Jquery carousel, navigate by dragging

Tags: jquery

Can anyone recommend a free jquery carousel which allows the user to navigate through by dragging across on the collection?

Alternatively, any ideas about how I would change a solution like this to accommodate the dragging functionality?
http://www.richardscarrott.co.uk/app/webroot/assets/javascript/jquery/carousel/demo/

To be clear, I'm not looking to drag and drop the items within the collection, I want to be able to click and pull the mouse to spin through the list.

EDIT - It turns out Richard rewrote the plugin using JQuery UI which has the features I'm after! - http://www.richardscarrott.co.uk/assets/javascript/jquery/ui-carousel/demo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/

Answer (score 2):

Well its already answered but just for the record, found this to be a pretty neat one as well, in fact the simplest as well as the best, for my similar requirements, that I came across:

http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/#enable-drag-drop